# Is the WP audio shortcode still relevant?

Tags: shortcode, audio

I'm not very familiar with audio integration so I'm wondering why I couldn't simply use the plain `<audio>` element? This would avoid the overhead of medialement.js that WP seems to use. I'm fine with targeting only recent browsers that support `<audio>` . Am I missing something? Cheers.

Comment: You can use `<audio>` if [this](https://caniuse.com/audio) satisfies you. WordPress is targeted at a large audience with different user agents and environments - `wp-mediaelement.js` might be necessary for backward compatibility. I disabled JS, and `<audio>` element worked for me. :)

Comment: Thanks @MayeenulIslam ! Based on those stats, I'm confident that my user base will be better served with a simple  `<audio>` element. Cheers!